# Switching to old Gmail UI

Tags: gmail, user-interface

About three weeks ago Gmail told me I could switch to a new look. I did, and it was terrible to say the least. Luckily Gmail let me revert back to the old look and I quickly went back. I was using the old look until now, but this morning I logged into my Gmail, and see that my Gmail opened with a new look. Besides I am unable to find the option to switch back to old look.

Can anyone please tell me how to do that?

This new look is barely usable.

Comment: What is your Operating System and in what browser do you have that problem?

Comment: I have two computers, both with dual boot. Ubuntu 11.10 and Windows 7. The problem persists across all web browsers I tried (6 of them) across all 4 of those OS installs. Those for certain are irrelevant factors though. Gmail (and probably facebook, twitter, and others) usually don't roll the changes at once to all users.

Comment: This is for the _old_ "new" interface (from back in 2011). The option to change back to that is long gone. For how to do it for the new (2018) interface, see [How to get rid of new Gmail design?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/117585/354)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a gear icon on the right top. Click on that, you will find the link to go back to old version.

or just follow the link
http://techzoom.org/easily-revert-back-to-gmails-old-look-from-new-cool-interface/

Comment: The option was there before. Not any more. :(

Comment: I checked few minutes back and it was there.

Comment: Gmail (and probably facebook, twitter, and others) rolls changes slowly to various users.

Comment: If possible, share the screenshot of your gmail. (considering your privacy)

Comment: [Here](http://imgur.com/rDSr8).

Comment: Oh wait, I found the option. I initially misunderstood what you meant by gear. Thanks for the answer, much appreciated!

Comment: Glad it helps...

Comment: There's this thing with gmail that new look we all got is going to be default soon and no one will be able to switch back to old one. This option guys are talking about above does not work for me.

Comment: The user interface has gone through a number of iterations since this was posted. The link to revert to the old inbox is no longer available.