# How to get rid of new Gmail design?

Tags: gmail, user-interface

So I've tried new Gmail design. I couldn't believe it was that ugly and unpleasant to use.

How to roll back to previous normal Gmail design?

New Gmail design:

[image: New Gmail design screen shot]

Comment: Please bear in mind that this change will became permanent in the near future.

Comment: Yes, we no longer have the ability to switch back to classic gmail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update: Users report that the rollback option disappears. See my note ↓

---

From the settings **`⚙`** button on the top right of your inbox - the first option is **`Go back to classic Gmail`**.

[image]

Note: I believe some day it will be permanent and you won't be able to use the old design anymore. [The same as happened with the new calendar.](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/114432/177684)
So keep that in mind.

Comment: We'll cross that bridge when we come to it. Now let's use normal one

Comment: this option disappeared for me. for anyone else too? see: https://imgur.com/a/Wem1xoU

Comment: @beta Yes, my father has seen it disappear from his options, though it still exists for me. He is not happy.

Comment: Disappeared for me too. =-( Looking for "go back to classic gmail" option- nowhere to  be found.

Comment: Unfortunately it was too expected 

Answer (score 1):

You can't anymore, you're stuck with the new Gmail look.

At least until Google's Gmail team decides to change it again in the future, but for now they've removed the "*Go back to classic Gmail*" option